# Bringing GeoServer CSS styled layer to Mapbox

Tags: geoserver, mapbox, css

I have a CSS styled layer in GeoServer 2.16.1 with CSS Extension and trying to bring my layer to Mapbox. Unfortunately it comes only as simple lines.

[image: CSS LineString Layer Geoserver]

[image: Preview from geoserver]

But if bring this layer to Mapbox it shows simple lines like below:

[image: Lines in React app with Mapbox]

```
map.addLayer({
      id: 'streets',
      type: 'line',
      source: {
        type: 'vector',
        tiles: [
          'http://localhost:80/geoserver/gwc/service/wmts?layer=geoapp:lines&tilematrixset=EPSG:900913&Service=WMTS&Request=GetTile&Version=1.0.0&Format=application/x-protobuf;type=mapbox-vector&TileMatrix=EPSG:900913:{z}&TileCol={x}&TileRow={y}'
        ]
      },
      'source-layer': 'lines'
      /* ,
      layout: {
        'line-join': 'round',
        'line-cap': 'round' 
      },
      paint: {
        'line-color': '#08363e',
        'line-width': 0.8
      } */
    });
```

Any hint, suggestion, or other way around?

Answer (score 2):

That is as expected, vector tiles are rendered (and [styled](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/vectortiles/tutorial.html#styling-vector-tiles)) at the client end so GeoServer ignores your styling when serving vector tiles.